# Azure Web Job always on

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I created web-job and deploy it. In settings I selected **web job run mode ->** **run continuously**. And after run my webjob I catch in toggle output console next message:

> [07/10/2015 16:29:48 > ef6a38: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
>   [07/10/2015 16:29:48 > ef6a38: SYS WARN] 'Always On' doesn't appear to
>   be enabled for this Web App. To ensure your continuous job doesn't
>   stop running when the SCM host is idle for too long, consider enabling
>   'Always On' in the configuration settings for your Web App. Note:
>   'Always On' is available only in Basic, Standard and Premium modes.
>   [07/10/2015 16:29:52 > ef6a38: SYS INFO] Run script
>   'OptimalyaServer.Migrations.exe' with script host -
>   'WindowsScriptHost' [07/10/2015 16:29:52 > ef6a38: SYS INFO] Status
>   changed to Running [07/10/2015 16:56:13 > ef6a38: SYS INFO] WebJob is
>   stopping due to website shutting down [07/10/2015 16:56:13 > ef6a38:
>   SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping [07/10/2015 16:56:18 > ef6a38:
>   ERR ] Thread was being aborted.

I don't know why it happens and how to fix it. I would like what my web-job worked without reboot and shutdown. 
Help me please with this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azure Web Apps go into a dormant state after a period of inactivity. This is useful for sites that do not have regular traffic. That is the default setting for new web apps. This is why the first request by a user against a web app that was dormant can take a few seconds longer since Azure has to "wake up" the web app.

Since your Webjob is set to run continuously, it means the webapp should never go into this dormant state. The webjob is part of the web app after all. You therefore need to configure your web app to stay "always on". It's a simply toggle in the General toggles of the CONFIGURE tab of your web app in the current management portal (right below the Web Sockets switch). In the new preview portal, click the Settings tab and then Application Settings to find the same toggle.

You can get more details on web apps configuration options at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/.

Comment: you are right that the site needs to be "Always On" for continuous WebJobs to work but you have some facts mixed up, the cost only relates to the site mode which could be: free, shared, basic, standard or premium (and also to the number of instances). the "Always On" feature doesn't cost extra but can only be configured in basic, standard or premium.

Comment: I never said that Always On costs extra. I only indicated that the cost of the web app will go up "since it will always stay up". If his site was getting enough traffic to keep the site up at all times, the cost will remain the same. But if the traffic was sporadic, then continuous uptime results in higher cost.

Comment: The cost of an Azure website is not related to the traffic it gets only to the mode and number of instances. "Since you only pay for cloud services when they are live/in use" - this is not true for an Azure website, you should remove this comment from your answer.

Comment: here on 2019 "Always On" is moved to "General Settings" tab inside "Settings" tab.